# include summation of value from one table when joining tables for sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sum, left-join

I have two tables, one with Tours and the other with Joiners. 
For the Tours table someone proposes a date, route, number of people and other factors for the tour.
For the Joiners table, groups click checkboxes in the Tours table indicating which Tours they would like to join.

I would like to show a column in the Tours table how many people are interested in that tour.

For the Joiners table I have:

```
$sql = "SELECT tourid,SUM(ppl) FROM joiners GROUP BY tourid";
```

which correctly calculates the total number of people interested in joining each tour, where ppl is the number of people in each group.

For the Tours (requests) table I tried:

```
$sql = "SELECT requests.id,requests.startdate,requests.wherestart,requests.duration,requests.ppl FROM requests
    LEFT JOIN joiners
    ON requests.id = joiners.tourid
    ORDER BY startdate";
```

but can't seem to figure out how to draw on the sum(ppl) amount from the Joiners table to insert it in the relevant column of the relevant tour/id of the Tour table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join your 1st query to the table `requests` like this:

```
SELECT r.id, r.startdate, r.wherestart, r.duration, r.ppl,
  r.ppl + SUM(j.ppl) AS total 
FROM requests AS r LEFT JOIN joiners AS j
ON r.id = j.tourid
GROUP BY r.id, r.startdate, r.wherestart, r.duration, r.ppl
ORDER BY r.startdate
```

In your question you say that the column `ppl` is in the table `joiners`, but your 2nd query contains a column `requests.ppl` which (I assume) you want to sum.
I included in the `SELECT` list a column `r.ppl`, but if this does not exist then delete it also from the `GROUP BY` clause.
It is a good practice to use aliases for the tables and qualify all the column names with these table aliases.

Comment: I'd like to SUM the j.ppl and add it to the r.ppl (both for a particular Tour (r.id)) in a new column in the Requests table.

Comment: wonderful, thank you very much, except I guess the + should be changed to ,

Comment: You said that you want them added: *I'd like to SUM the j.ppl and add it to the r.ppl*.